# stack raster as muti-bands TIF file

Tags: python, gdal

I have 15 years' rasters along time serials. Each year contain 46 rasters.The file such as N2000001.tif, N2000009.tif,......, N2000361.tif

I want to stack same year rasters as single file.Such as N2000.tif, which contians 46 bands.

Run code as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from osgeo import gdal
import os

inpath=''
outpath=''

driver=gdal.GetDriverByName('GTiff')
driver.Register()
file0=
data0=gdal.Open(file0,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)  # base file for driver.CreatCopy()

 # *get the all tif rasters filenames*
filenames = [filename for filename in sorted(os.listdir(inpath)) 
            if os.path.splitext(filename)[1]=='.tif'] 
# *sort all rasters name* 
single=sorted(set(filenames),key=filenames.index)

for year in range(2000,2016):    
     i=1
      #buid each year stack file
     outfile=os.path.join(outpath,'N'+str(year)+'.tif')  
     outds=driver.CreateCopy(outfile,data0)
     for name in single:
          if str(year) in name:        # *run each year*
              file=os.path.join(inpath,name)
              print name+'is processing'

              data=gdal.Open(file,gdal.GA_ReadOnly)
              band=data.GetRasterBand(1)
              arr=band.ReadAsArray()
              outds.GetRasterBand(i).WriteArray(arr)

              i+=1                 # *the band sequence number*
      outds=None
```

system hint error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-5-a57257d55372>", line 35, in <module>
    outds.GetRasterBand(i).WriteArray(arr)

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'WriteArray'
```

Comment: You want Create instead of CreateCopy which closes the dataset with a single band... when you create you specify the number of bands to create.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is probably occurring because `CreateCopy` is producing a geotiff with the same number of bands as `file0`, which has `n` bands. When trying to access band `n+1` of `outds`, the returned object will be None. `n` is less than 46 in this case.

You need a proper image template to use as `file0` if you want to keep using `CreateCopy`. Otherwise you should use `Create` and set the number of bands, image size, and data type explicitly.

Comment: That's right.  need to set number of bands `outds=driver.Create(outfile,col,row,46,3)`. Thx very much!